# Using JavaScript to return a Video

Tags: javascript, html, web

I just started to create my own website using html, css and js.
I want it to have a background video, right now I do it with `<div class="bg"><video src="res/res1.mp4" muted autoplay loop></video></div>` and it works fine.
But I want to change the video per button click to make it dynamic and I saw someone do it like `<video src=testFunction() muted autoplay loop></video>`.

My question is: how do I return a video in a function?

Comment: `const testFunction = () => { return "res/res1.mp4"; }`. Make your function return a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to return a video , you need to change the src of video.
using

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")
video.setAttribute(src, "url-of-video);
```

you question is how to return a video.you can do it by

```
const testFunction = function(){
  return "url-of-video"
}
```